# Why .NET Standard 2.0 has full support for Span even if MS lists it as unsupported?

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, c#-7.3

I started digging around about spans, and I have found official reference information that it is supported as `System.Span<T>` since .NET Standard 2.1 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0#applies-to). However, I have Xamarin Application with .NET Standard 2.0 and C# 7.3, where I can use `System.Span` without issues, I can even use `Reverse()` which I have seen discussions dealing with lack of it in Standard 2.0.

I am so confused about that, can anyone explain why I can use it, where it shouldn't work?

Comment: _"I have Xamarin Application with .NET Standard 2.0 and C# 7.3"_ - you can't target .NET Standard 2.0 in a Xamarin Application project, [only a library project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/net-standard?tabs=windows). What is your startup/entrypoint project **actually** targeting? Please post as much of your `.csproj` file as you can.

Comment: I am not sure how to get version, whole application is being run on Xamarin.Android project, which doesn't have .NET version specification in it. I know that libraries have Standard 2.0, no idea what is actual version it's being run on, but I mean I can use span within Standard 2.0 project

Comment: What actual problem do you need to solve? If you're convinced that it's a combination that shouldn't work then just plain don't use it.

Comment: @AdamKaczmarski Just share the first ~20 lines of your `.csproj` file.

Answer (score 2):

`Span<T>` as part of System.Runtime.dll is not available in .NET Standard 2.0.

There's a NuGet package ([System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory)), but that provides only those types and not the changes to the BCL to use `Span<T>`.

Comment: Well, that's a problem I am looking at - it should not be available, but I can freely import `System.Span` within .NET Standard 2.0 project. I am confused, because everything says I cannot, except that I can as I see in person.

Comment: As long as you reference System.Memory, you have the `Span<T>` type, as stated in the package docs.